# Should I invalidate tokens when password changes?

Tags: api, symfony, jwt, token, platform

I am using API Platform and JWT token to authenticate during my requests

I am wondering if I should disconnect user's sessions if its password changes/resets?
I heard it's not supposed to happen wtih JWT and it's not a part of the bundle (https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle), but, is it fine not to disconnect user's sessions if its password gets changed? I'm asking about security point of view

I would appreciate any help

Comment: I would say *no*.  Of course, it depends, but PWD and a token are different "credentials"

Answer (score 0):

It depends ... :)
PWD and a token actually are "different credentials"

If User **can only** change PWD via web UI with a "traditional web-requests" (Something like: `Homepage → Login → MyAccount → Settings/Security`) and Token is **only** to use with an API then I would say **NO**, no need to invalidate.

If Frontend build with some JS Lib like React/Vue/Svelte and uses JWT to access secured areas, probably, you ***should invalidate***, since one with a valid and non-expired JWT could still have access after PWD was set to a new one.
It would be a nightmare if some hacker, who somehow acquired your valid JWT, would still have access to `User → MyAccount → Settings` and potentially be able to do bad stuff after You explicitly changed PWD

Comment: My app is api platform back-end and vue.js front-end. My user logins with credentials and receives a token who has a validity of one hour. This token is then used to access everything in the application, with API requests (with axios) such as creating a product/category for admins or just editing my own account for a non-admin user. According to what you said, I understand I should invalidate token?

Comment: @mat In your case. I would say YES. When PWD reset happens → all **other** tokens for this user should be invalidated, BUT it has drawbacks and cloud be inconvenient. Each time a user changes PWD → user will be forced to log in.

Comment: Yes, user will be forced to log in, but I don't see it as a problem. This is what happens on Amazon for example, if I change my password, I need to login again and I think it's normal :)